# Anchor links in bootstrap don't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I am using bootstrap 3.2.0. I have some content in the tabs and I want to create an anchor link to this content in the tabs to different websites. Here is my code:

```
        <div class="bs-docs-example">
         <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                <li><a href="#1A" data-toggle="tab"> Sample#1 </h1></a></li>
                <li><a href="#2A" data-toggle="tab"> Sample#2 </h1></a></li>
             </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">

                <div class="tab-pane" id="1A">

                    <li id="ndf_35"></li>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="2A">

                    <li id="ndf_36"></li>


                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I create the link like this :

```
    <a href="http://www.example.com/page1#ndf_36">some text </a>
```

But it's not working. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your HTML is badly formed...you have closing `h1` tags without opening tags.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Where are you putting the "some text" link that you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6f7fuL/)**

Its working fine.

Check that

- You have included jquery (you need jquery for bootstrap.js)
- You have included bootstrap.js
- open `<h1>` tags

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Sorry it's my mistake with <h1> I corrected this. About other: